# CPLEX TOOL Integrating with JAVA using Eclipse Editor

Tags: java

How can I solve this error of CPLEX integration with JAVA:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\System32\cplex124.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
java.library.path must point to the directory containing the CPLEX shared library
try invoking java with java -Djava.library.path=...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ilog.cplex.Cplex.CPXopenCPLEX([I)J
    at ilog.cplex.Cplex.CPXopenCPLEX(Native Method)
    at ilog.cplex.CplexI.init(CplexI.java:5722)
    at ilog.cplex.CplexI.<init>(CplexI.java:611)
    at ilog.cplex.IloCplex.<init>(IloCplex.java:10384)
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:10)
```

Comment: The message seems pretty clear to me "Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform", so either use a 32bit jvm **or** a 64bit version of cplex

Comment: can you tell me the link or the source from where i can get the cplex 64 bit version....